# Internal Server Error while run laravel on localhost

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner on laravel. Now, I want to run laravel project on localhost. Now, what I have done? I have create `index.blade.php` file inside `resource/view/index.blade.php` and modify `web.php` file inside `routes/web.php`

routes/web.php

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('index', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

resources/view/index.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Laravel start</h1>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I have change `server.php` to `index.php` and move `.htaccess` file from `public` to root directory and restart `apache` server. but it show me `500 Internal Server Error`. I have run `localhost/laravel` but its not working. So, How can I fix this problem? Please help me.

Error occuring

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.32 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Thank You

Comment: provide your error with details, example : the code line etc.

Comment: Please look at once @TharakaDilshan

Comment: why you want to change server.php file to index.php file ?

Comment: You could follow the [Installation instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#installing-laravel) and not rename core files. `public` should be your server's DocumentRoot.

Comment: I have follow instruction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788285/how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan

Comment: in local environment there no need to change those files. when you use an framework please try to understand its structure and purpose of it.

Comment: ok when I start php artisan it start laravel on `127.0.0.1:8000` but How can I run other file using this. it basically run `welcome.blade.php` file but if I have `index.blade.php` so how can I run this file on `127.0.0.1:8000` @EmtiazZahid

Comment: You can by calling your routes in your browser. So `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` should show your defined route. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

```
after fresh install , just run command "php artisan serve" , 
because server.php is modified to run server on any directory without putting project in xampp\htdocs , 
If You want to run through localhost replace index.php and .htaccess from public to root directory of project
hope this helps :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change any file on laravel project if you need just create new folder or file then run it as you know.

if you want to run only laravel project you can run it but if you want to work with database you should use xampp or wampp localhost server.

Hope you may success.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to various issues:

- Artisan serve is not working
- Trigger file permission issue
- Folder permission issue
- Apache server status

You need test one by one like create a separate folder and then inside a new file with simple `echo "I am here";` and see if it works.

Next step you need to check command or alternates

Then you need to check permissions of folder and files

If still issue, then maybe need to check into server settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys have **cloned project** from a remote repository or **local project**

1. Make sure you have *.env.example* file
2. If exist copy content and write on new file called *.env*
3. If there is no .env.example file create *.env* file and paste file from fresh laravel project *.env* file

This way I solved my issue. I hope it will help you too!!!

Answer (score 0):

in my case i didnt set right data for **DB_DATABASE ,DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD** in

> .env

use these data:

```
DB_DATABASE = YourDatabaseName
DB_USERNAME = root
DB_PASSWORD =
```