# I'm facing problem in laravel that is "This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect."

Tags: php, laravel

I face this error only when "php artisan serve" command is not running. If this command is running then there is no such a error, but as i closed command prompt this error occurs. i have also changed port but no vain.
Kindly help me.I would like to mention here that I'm using Window 10 OS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a localhost issue. What are you using for localhost?

Comment: `php artisan serve` runs the server, so if you don't have it running, there is no server to connect

Comment: I'm using XAMPP

Comment: `netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1`

can you try this command in your xampp console? Let me know if it works after

Comment: What port are you trying to connect to?   artisan serves on port 8000 by default, XAMPP likely uses 80..

Comment: Ali but laravel is trying to connect through the artisan on other port

Comment: Xampp console ? i don't know about it.Is it CMD ? if not then kindly guide me how to access it.

Comment: i'm using http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Flash Thunder bro then whats solution ?
Can't i run it on localhost using XAMPP ?
Is it compulsory to run "php artisan serve" command untill i'm working with laravel ?
Is there no any solution ?

Comment: @AliBhutta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788285/how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan

Comment: The solution is to not use port 8000...  Use the port XAMPP is configured on if you want to use XAMPP..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a HTTP server (like WAMP or similar installed), you'll need to keep the Command Prompt / Terminal window running at all times. Closing the window or stopping the `php artisan server` command will terminate the server that's running the website.

If you want a persistent server, you should look into server software like WAMP or XAMPP.

Note that this is expected behavior for the `php artisan serve` command.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP but still error occuring. Kindly help me

Comment: If you're already using XAMPP then no need to use `php artisan serve`. Make sure XAMPP is configured correctly to point to your Laravel project and, including port number. Add details on your XAMPP configuration to your question so we can help further.

Comment: @ Niraj Shah   how to Add details on myXAMPP configuration ? kidnly guide me Thanks

Comment: I don't use XAMPP. Please consult the documentation or visit the XAMPP website for help.

Answer (score 1):

because with this kind of server (like: LARAGON), running 'php artisan serve' is necessary, so if you close the terminal, 'php artisan serve' will automaticaly stop running, then the server will stop too, then you can't reach anymore your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a persistent server, you should look into server software like WAMP or XAMPP.

Note that this is expected behavior for the

```
php artisan serve command
```