# Changing navigation and link URLs?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, base-url

I am new to laravel and this will be inappropriate question. Although I searched I couldn't find the answer. My project run smoothly with php artisan serve command. I just wanted to remove the artisan command. So I added my project into htdoc folder of XAMPP. Then I changed according to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28799205/3558507

When I run my project by typing URL on chrome as "`http://localhost/MonitorEnto/public/home`" home page is appearing. But when I tried to navigate through links and tabs its not working, URL is showing in my browser as "`http://localhost/add_company`".

I changed config/app.php line as `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/MonitorEnto/public/'),` But still problem is there. Please help me to solve this matter. Thanks/

Comment: You have to change navigate menu as you declare in `route`. Check you `route` file and add proper `route` in proper `menu`. Hope this will solve your issue. And you should link up style/scripts file properly.

Comment: Thanks. I have added <a href="{{url('/....')}}" > to all links. its working

Comment: Glad to know that. Please accept my answer so that other one can get this as helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change navigation menu as you declared in `route`. Check you route file and add proper `route` name in respective menu. Hope this will solve your issue. And you should link up `style/scripts` file properly.

Suppose for home:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

You can call in blade file `{{ route('home') }}` or defined `url` as `{{ url('/home') }}`.

Answer (score 0):

step-1 :Go to your Project folder in public folder Exampale: path = yourproject/public/

Step-2 :copy 2 files index.php and .htaccess paste in your project root folder

Step-3 :open index.php file and modfy this code

require DIR.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; //change to this path require DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Turn On The Lights |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights. | This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it | will load up this application so that we can run it and send | the responses back to the browser and delight our users. | */

$app = require_once DIR.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
//change to this path $app = require_once DIR.'/bootstrap/app.php';

step-4 :Open file yourproject\app\routes\web.php add this route

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Step-5 : run this url in your locahost
http://localhost/yourproject/home