# How can I run my Laravel project without cmd command "php artisan serve"?

Tags: php, laravel

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@hujjaj.dev
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\hujjaj_app_new\public"
ServerName hujjaj.dev
ErrorLog "logs/hujjaj.dev-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/hujjaj.dev-access.log" common
```

I am doing so in my virtual host file and update 127.0.0.1 hujjaj.dev then i restart XAMPP and after that I navigate to localhost/hujjaj.dev but showing 404|Not Found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788285/how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan Hope It will help You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Laravel without Artisan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788285/how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan)

Comment: you should add this to your hosts file `127.0.0.1 hujjaj.dev`   file path `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and then go to hujjaj.dev directly without localhost

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
  DocumentRoot “D:\laravel-gkb\public”
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  ServerName laravel-gkb.test
  <Directory “D:\laravel-gkb\public”>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add the save domain in your `hosts` file

```
127.0.0.2 hujjaj.dev
```

Refer this for more details : [link](https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/configure-a-virtual-host-for-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows-10-d3f0068e7e1b)

Comment: Fine and Thanks Rijosh I try this and its working at 127.0.0.2 but my site pictures are not showing as i used storage for picture saving. please guide me

Comment: Storage image paths cannot be shown unless you set 777 permission for the directory. You can add storage link to the public using command `php artisan storage:link`. Now you can use the storage file links directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is another way to run laravel project, with following command..

> php -S 127.0.0.1:8001 server.php

This will run your application at `127.0.0.1:8001` mentioned address.

**Note**: laravel default entry point is `server.php` thats why we mentioned it. other wise it will be `index.php`