# Object Not Found in Laravel - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have developed whole working project in Laravel and finally to give someone else to use it, i have to remove command **php artisan serve** to run the project. I just want the user to type **localhost/projectname**  and start to use the project on localhost. Hence i followed this link - [how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788285/how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan).

But now only this link is working properly -

```
localhost/projectname
```

And all these links given below throws error :

```
localhost/product_list
localhost/client_list
```

OUTPUT :

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6tCl.png)

But if i type these, it works :

```
localhost/projectname/product_list
localhost/projectname/client_list
```

I tried to change base_url (APP_URL) so that whatever is been applied in url should be in suffix of APP_URL

```
//.env file
APP_URL=http://localhost/projectname

//app.php
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/projectname'),
```

Then too all routes(product_list) gets attached to `localhost/product_list` and not `localhost/projectname/product_list`

I want to make it work like this =>  `localhost/projectname/product_list`

OR

May be some other solution.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the accepted answer or other answers?

Comment: @shaedrich followed it well

Comment: @shaedrich followed the accepted answer, but stuck in this situation. I dont know why BASE_URL (APP_URL) is not changing.

Comment: Maybe this is the easier solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251427/7451109

Comment: @shaedrich I have reverted/Undo all changes back and got back to my original project. And now followed your given link. But how should i run my project now ? With **php artisan serve** or directly **localhost/projectname**. Because localhost/projectname says **404|Not found** and when i run **127.0.0.1:8000** it require php artisan serve

Comment: `localhost/product_list` with an apache or nginx server running locally

Comment: @shaedrich I am using apache (Xampp). And also i just checked that its working without php artisan serve but like this **localhost/projectname/public/product_list**. I want it like this :  **localhost/projectname/product_list**. What should i do ?

Comment: If you configure your apache/.htaccess properly according to the answer I posted, it points to `public/` folder so you don't have to include `/public/` into your URL. Have you done that?

Comment: @shaedrich You are right but when i type : **localhost/projectname** its shows **404|Not Found**. And even after manually entering **localhost/projectname/public** homepage works, but other links on hover shows url pointing like this : **localhost/product_list**  and not **localhost/projectname/public/product_list**

Comment: @shaedrich I have once again reverted all changes, all started fresh. This time I noticed that even without adding **.htaccess** in root folder, Manually typing **localhost/ims/public** works, but only for homepage, not for other links. I have to make it work with **php artisan serve**, which i dont want.